# How to get a list with description of all dba packages

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need an overview in my application of all packages you can use in an sql or pl/sql statement from the database.
I need the package name and procedures/functions with there description.

So for example:

dbms_output: Package to give some output

dbms_output.put_line: procedure to return some output to serveroutput

Can this be done using a normal select ?

I tried already the following which gives me data but not a description and not the procedures and or functions of the packages:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Owner, Object_Type, Object_Name FROM DBA_Objects_AE
     WHERE Owner IN (
       'SYS', 'OUTLN', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP',
       'LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ORDSYS',
       'ORDPLUGINS', 'OEM_MONITOR', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY',
       'WK_TEST', 'WKUSER', 'MDSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'DMSYS',
       'WMSYS', 'OLAPDBA', 'OLAPSVR', 'OLAP_USER',
       'OLAPSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'MDDATA',
       'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'XDB', 'ODM')
     AND Object_Type IN ('PACKAGE', 'TYPE')
     ORDER BY Owner, Object_Type, Object_Name;


select *
from all_objects
where object_type = 'PACKAGE';
```

Comment: Can't you just point people to the [packages and types reference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/toc.htm) (or the [PDF version](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758.pdf))? You can get the procedure and functions, and even the arguments, from the data dictionary but I doubt the descriptions are stored anywhere.

Comment: That overview is right in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/intro.htm#i1010103

Comment: I know this info is in the manual. But I have an application that displays this information where they need to check boxes to say if they use it or not, which is important for the application I have build. And instead of typing all the information from the manual into a table or so I would like to use a select statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the procedures and functions for the packages, and object types (member functions), from `all_procedures`:

```
select ao.owner, ao.object_type, ao.object_name, ap.procedure_name
from all_objects ao
left join all_procedures ap
on ap.owner = ao.owner
and ap.object_name = ao.object_name
where ao.owner in (
  'SYS', 'OUTLN', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP',
  'LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ORDSYS',
  'ORDPLUGINS', 'OEM_MONITOR', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY',
  'WK_TEST', 'WKUSER', 'MDSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'DMSYS',
  'WMSYS', 'OLAPDBA', 'OLAPSVR', 'OLAP_USER',
  'OLAPSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'MDDATA',
  'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'XDB', 'ODM')
and ao.object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'TYPE')
order by ao.owner, ao.object_type, ao.object_name, ap.procedure_name;

OWNER                          OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME                    PROCEDURE_NAME               
------------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
DBSNMP                         PACKAGE             DM_FMTLIB                      MGMT_DM_GEN_AC                 
DBSNMP                         PACKAGE             DM_FMTLIB                      MGMT_DM_GEN_AC_FH              
DBSNMP                         PACKAGE             DM_FMTLIB                      MGMT_DM_GEN_AC_FS              
DBSNMP                         PACKAGE             DM_FMTLIB                      MGMT_DM_GEN_ANYC               
...
```

If you want to show the arguments, if only to distinguish between overloaded procedures, you can join to `all_arguments`. But not sure how manageable that will be:

```
select ao.object_type
  ||' '|| ao.owner ||'.'|| ao.object_name
  || case when ap.procedure_name is not null then
    '.'|| ap.procedure_name
    || case when count(aa.argument_name) > 0 then
      '('|| listagg(aa.argument_name, ',')
        within group (order by position) ||')'
    end
  end as object_info
from all_objects ao
left join all_procedures ap
on ap.owner = ao.owner
and ap.object_name = ao.object_name
and ap.object_id = ao.object_id
left join all_arguments aa
on aa.owner = ap.owner
and aa.object_name = ap.procedure_name
and aa.object_id = aa.object_id
and aa.subprogram_id = ap.subprogram_id
where ao.owner in (
  'SYS', 'OUTLN', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP',
  'LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ORDSYS',
  'ORDPLUGINS', 'OEM_MONITOR', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY',
  'WK_TEST', 'WKUSER', 'MDSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'DMSYS',
  'WMSYS', 'OLAPDBA', 'OLAPSVR', 'OLAP_USER',
  'OLAPSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'MDDATA',
  'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'XDB', 'ODM')
and ao.object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'TYPE')
and ao.object_name = 'DBMS_OUTPUT'
group by ao.object_type, ao.owner, ao.object_name, ap.procedure_name,
  ao.object_id, ap.subprogram_id
order by ao.owner, ao.object_type, ao.object_name, ap.procedure_name;
```

I've restricted to just show `DBMS_OUTPUT` as an example:

```
OBJECT_INFO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.DISABLE
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(BUFFER_SIZE,LOG_TYPE,LOG_TARGET,LOG_LEVEL)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE(FILE,ID,LINE,BUFFER,DATATYPE,STATUS,BYTE_MODE,LEN)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES(LINES,NUMLINES)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES(LINES,NUMLINES)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(A)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(A)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT
```

Or to show return types for functions:

```
select ao.object_type
  ||' '|| ao.owner ||'.'|| ao.object_name
  || case when ap.procedure_name is not null then
    '.'|| ap.procedure_name
    || case when count(aa.argument_name) > 0 then
      '('|| listagg(aa.argument_name, ',')
        within group (order by position) ||')'
    end
    || case when min(aa.position) = 0 then ' RETURN '
      || max(case when position = 0 then aa.pls_type end) end
  end as object_info
...
```

For `DBMS_RANDOM`:

```
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.INITIALIZE(VAL)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL RETURN NUMBER
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM RETURN BINARY_INTEGER
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.SEED(VAL)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.SEED(VAL)
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.STRING(OPT,LEN) RETURN VARCHAR2
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.TERMINATE
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE RETURN NUMBER
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(LOW,HIGH) RETURN NUMBER
PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_RANDOM
```

You can obviously format the information however you want, use data types instead of argument names, etc. so this is just a starting point.

I doubt there are descriptions or even comments anywhere though. This gives you a lot of things to have checkboxes against, and to write descriptions for. Referring out to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/toc.htm) seems more sensible, but depends what you want to do with the information.

Comment: Thanks a lot this seems nice. If nobody comes up with an answer about the comments I will accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you take the HTML documentation from Oracle and read it with a DOM Parser. This prevents you from making "copy-paste" hundreds of times.