# PLSQL packages with procedures in data dictionary

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can i get list of packages with their procedures inside, with help of data dictionary views?
I need to get this list for a user lets say 'HR' , and to be listed like:

```
PackageName1: Procedure1, Procedure2,...
PackageName2: Procedure1, Procedure2,...
```

I used this line statement but i couldn't figure out how to get procedure lists inside of those packages:

```
select distinct name, type 
from all_source 
where owner ='HR' 
and type='PACKAGE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this answer to get packages and procedure details
[How to get a list with description of all dba packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545184/how-to-get-a-list-with-description-of-all-dba-packages)

to get idea how to extract info

and then reformat output using LISTAGG function